# integer variable on xpath element python

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation

I'm trying to scrape a html table that every 30 minutes is added a new row underneath. So I need add on the xpath element a variable integer to the  value that will be incremented every 30 minutes.
My code now is like this:

```
lastline = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@width="517"]/tbody/tr[8]/td[8]')
```

I try simple concatenation did didn't work because I have double quotation"" inside the single quotation''.
So I decided put the table width value in a variable as well to then work on the tr value  later

```
 tablewidth = 517
 lastline = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/table[@width=' " + table + "/tbody/tr[8]/td[8']")
```

then I would be able to use the simple concatenation like mentioned a couple times here in slack. But then I started to face another issue, seems that I can't concatenate a string with a integer variable, seems to be a very simple thing to solve but i'm stuck.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Is an f-string what you are looking for? `f'//table[@width="{tablewdith}"]/tbody/tr[8]/td[8]'`. You need to clean up your example a bit... the strings aren't the same and you use tablewidth and table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert `tablewidth` into a string with `str(tablewidth)` as such:

```
tablewidth = 517
lastline = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/table[@width=\"" + str(tablewidth) + "\"]/tbody/tr[8]/td[8]")
```

I cleaned up the code a little bit as well because I think your string was incorrect. It now looks like this:

```
print("/table[@width=\"" + str(tablewidth) + "\"]/tbody/tr[8]/td[8]")
```

```
/table[@width="517"]/tbody/tr[8]/td[8]
```